# How to resolve request methos 'POST' not supported?

Tags: spring, jsp, tags

I want to design a quick registration page which is placed at the footer when I submit the field, It is showing some error "Request method POST not supported". Someone, please help me to come out of this error.

I have modified the attribute of the form commandName as modelAttribute, but still, the error exists.

1. This is jsp front end.

> ```
>  <%@ tag body-content="empty" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
>     <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
>     <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
>     <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
>     <c:url value="/setSubscribe" var="subscribe"></c:url> 
>     <form:form action="${subscribe}" method="post" modelAttribute="subscribeForm">
>     <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
>       <label class="form-check-label radio-inline"> 
>           <input type="radio"  class="form-check-input" value="gender" name="gender"  value="Male"/> Male
>       </label>
>       <label class="form-check-label radio-inline"> 
>           <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="gender" name="gender"  value="Female"/> Female
>       </label>    
>       <br></br>
>       <div class="row">
>           <div class="col-sm-3">
>               <input  class="form-control" name="firstName"  placeholder="First Name"></input> 
>           </div>
>           <div class="col-sm-3">
>               <input class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
>           </div>
>           <div class="col-sm-3">
>               <input class="form-control" name="email"  placeholder="Your Email Address"></input>
>           </div>
>           <div class="col-sm-3">
>               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBSCRIBE</button>
>           </div>
>       </div>
>     </form:form>
> ```

2. Here is my controller.

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/setSubscribe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
>   private String doSubscribe(@ModelAttribute("subscribeForm") final SubscribeForm form)
>   {
>       final RegisterData registerData = new RegisterData();
>       registerData.setFirstName(form.getFirstName());
>       registerData.setLastName(form.getLastName());
>       registerData.setSex(form.getGender());
>       registerData.setLogin(form.getEmail());
>
>       final CerCustomerFacadeImpl customerFacadeImpl = new CerCustomerFacadeImpl();
>       try
>       {
>           customerFacadeImpl.newCerRegister(registerData, true);
>       }
>       catch (final Exception e)
>       {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>       return "";
>   }
> ```

It should have to behave according to the business which has been mentioned in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Write your controller method with @ResponseBody annotation and consumes property of  @RequestMapping  annotation, as following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setSubscribe", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
private String doSubscribe(@ModelAttribute("subscribeForm") final SubscribeForm form)
  {
      return "";
  }
```